# Is there a way for a notification to know the application is already open? Or specifically which activity is open?

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, android-notifications

I've got an activity that only opens via a notification. That notification can pop up while in the activity as well. Is there a way to tell the notification the activity is already open so I can change its behavior accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for the notification to know, it just has a `PendingIntent` that is fired when it's clicked. But you can be smart about handling the intent.

For your case I think you should look at [Activity launch modes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode). Specifically I think adding `launchMode="singleTop"` to your `<activity>` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` does exactly what you want.